# SELECT a row WHERE column + x minutes

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am trying to find a way to select a row where a date column + x minutes is superior or inferior to given value.

Example :

```
$theday = "2020-04-07 14:30:25";

$query = $mysqli("SELECT * FROM table WHERE columndate + 5 minutes < '$theday'");
```

This query is meant to show what I am trying to do.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What you posted doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thing is that, future visitors will potentially figure that your code works as posted, think of that ;-) Really, there are some who actually don't know how to use database code.

Comment: Why not just change $theday to be 5 minutes less? It should have the exact same semantics.

Comment: It's because I can have multiple row, with different time, but need to compare from a date thats change :) . Couldn't do this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TIMESTAMPDIFF`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, columndate, ?)) < 5;
```

To the `?` placeholder you should bind `$theday` variable.

This would find all records where your day timestamp and column are within 5 minutes of each other.  If you want the opposite, where the two timestamps are at least 5 minutes apart, then change the direction of the inequality.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm not sure `ABS` is required based on the code in the question?